# How can I make a filterlist work for objects within objects? It does work for other data types

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, filter

I have a problem understanding why the following code does not work.

```
  initializeItems(): void {
    this.notesService.load();}
```

`this.notesService.load()` creates an object with multiple objects, such as for example notes which then has several attributes such as notes.title. `filterList(evt){}` is triggered when input is registered in a search bar. When I used a list the code works, but it doesn't work for my objects.

```
  filterList(evt) {
    this.initializeItems();
    const searchTerm = evt.srcElement.value;

    if (!searchTerm) {
      return;
    }
    this.notesService.notes = this.notesService.notes.filter(currentGoal => {
      console.log(this.notesService.notes)
      if (currentGoal.title && searchTerm) {
        if (currentGoal.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

if I remove `this.initializeItems()`; from `filterList(evt)` I can see that the filtering works. However, I want to include `this.initializeItems()` so that when a user uses the backspace the previous filtering is ignored and all objects are displayed again. When I do not include `this.initializeItems()` I can see that `this.notesService.notes` is empty after filtering.

When I do include `this.initializeItems()` no filtering occurs. Could someone tell me why this is not working? When I use, for example, a list with data these functions work fine.

To clarify what initializeItems() does where Note contains an id, title, content and date.

```
export class NotesService {

  public notes: Note[] = [];
  public loaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(private storage: Storage,private navCtrl: NavController) { }
  load(): Promise<boolean> {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      this.storage.get('notes').then((notes) => {

        if(notes != null){
          this.notes = notes;
        }
        this.loaded = true;
        resolve(true);
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this without knowing more about `initializeItems`. You've got a lot of state in this function (`this.notesService.notes`, `currentGoal.title`, etc) that we just have no visibility into.

Comment: Thanks, does my update clarify it more?

Comment: @johmsmitth load is async, you cannot expect it to be done when you call the function. You will have to wait for the promise to resolve, to continue your code

Comment: Thanks! how can I do this?